# How to run sve intrinsics in Windows?

Tags: arm, sve

I use simde to run SVE intrinsics in Visual Studio,but only a few sve intrinsics included in simde. how to run sve intrinsics in Windows except simde?

Answer (score 0):

SIMDE only has a few [SVE intrinsics](https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde/tree/master/simde/arm/sve) - but they could still be a useful example for implementing yourself in your own project. But beyond that Arm Intrinsics documentation is very useful.

Here's the overview: https://developer.arm.com/Architectures/Scalable%20Vector%20Extensions 
An introductory video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGCcPo4UAHs 
and the [full list of developer documentation](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/#cf-navigationhierarchiesproducts=Architectures,Instruction%20Sets,SIMD%20ISAs,SVE).